# Two data frame combine on the basis of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe with different index df1=

|  | Id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 211 | Car | Benz |
| 1 | 212 | Bike | Yamaha |
| 2 | 213 | Laptop | Dell |

and df2=

|  | Model | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C Class | 55L |
| 1 | GLA | 45L |
| 2 | A Class | 42L |
| 0 | YZF R15 | 2L |
| 1 | YZF MT15 | 1.7L |
| 2 | FZ 25 | 1.5L |
| 0 | Alienware | 3L |
| 1 | XPS | 1.8L |
| 2 | G3 | 1.4L |

Is it possible to combine both data frame based on index value?

Can I get an Output like this?

| Id | A | B | Model | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211 | Car | Benz | C Class | 55L |
| 211 | Car | Benz | GLA | 45L |
| 211 | Car | Benz | A Class | 42L |
| 212 | Bike | Yamaha | YZF R15 | 2L |
| 212 | Bike | Yamaha | YZF MT15 | 1.7L |
| 212 | Bike | Yamaha | FZ 25 | 1.5L |
| 213 | Laptop | Dell | Alienware | 3L |
| 213 | Laptop | Dell | XPS | 1.8L |
| 213 | Laptop | Dell | G3 | 1.4L |

How do I write in python to get this kind of data frame?

Comment: Your output DF doesn't look based on index, but in row order or another field.  In df1 row (0, 211, Car, Benz) is joined with rows with index (0, 1, 2) from df2. Is there a typo in your output?.  As I see row (0, 211, Car, Benz) must match df2's rows with index 0m for example ( (0, C Class), (0, YZF R15), (0, Alienware) )

Comment: The df2 I got from a json which was in a pandas column. so the index in df2 is 0,1,2, 0,1,2. I want to merge the two data frame based to give the same id 211 for car,  212 for bike and 213 for Laptop. Is it possible?. Is there any other method

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you need another field in `df2` to identify groups of rows associated with one id in `df1`. Maybe there are many ways, some of them are more efficient than this one, but it works.

Use a custom function to set a new field called `group` (from JSON group) and then use that new field in a merge.

1. **Add new field**. Based on the current index set a group. I supposed that each group always has exactly three elements and the last one has an index equal to 2.

```py
def set_group(df):
    group = 0
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        row['group'] = group
        if i == 2:
            group += 1
        
df2['group'] = None
set_group(df2)
```

[image]

2. **Merge DataFrames**

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    left=df1,
    right=df2,
    how='inner',
    left_index=True,
    right_on='group'
)
```

[image]